# How to install and use Graph Data Science and APOC lbraries in Neo4j Virtual Machine Enterprise?

Tags: neo4j

I want to learn to work with a Neo4j VM Enterprise.

Usually I work on Neo4j desktop and I have a project working on it.

I don't know how to use GDS and APOC libraries in a Neo4j VM.

What do I have to do ?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/docker/) and [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/docker-run-neo4j/) for documentation on how to use neo4j with Docker.

Also, if you are deploying to the cloud, the neo4j [Cloud Deployments](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/cloud-deployments/) documentation should be helpful.